# Process memory increases much faster with gflags +ust

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, windbg, gflags

I've got stuck in a problem with **gflags** when trying to find some memory leaks in a windows app.

When I turn on the **ust** flag (in order to collect memory allocations stack traces) the memory of my application increases much faster than it does when the flag is off (it reaches to 800MB in 10 min aprox. which is far from the 50-100MB/day I get when the flag is off).

I've read that there is a maximum for stack traces of 32MB, so I suppose this shouldn't be a problem.

The computer is a *4x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5410 @ 2.33GHz*.

If someone could give me some hint I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace database is not the only impact of the ust flag. It also adds at least 32 bytes to each allocation, in order to store its stack trace id. This could explain your memory increase if lots of small allocations are involved.
If you launch the process with an attached debugger or compiled the process with debug target, the windows heaps will be set in debug mode and the overhead per allocation will be even bigger.

Comment: Thank you plodoc, then what would you propose to do in order to find the memory leaks?

Comment: You may try !heap -stat command and !heap -flt windbg commands. !heap -stat will list the heaps by reverse order of size. Look at the first ones with !heap -stat -h <heap handle> to get the category of object size that uses the most space. Then !heap -flt s <size> will list all the objects of this size. Look into these object to see if you can identify them.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maximum trace database size using /tracedb SizeInMB See the [MSDN Gflags documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265901.aspx) for chapter and verse. By default there is no maximum size which most likely explains the behaviour you have seen.

Comment: I've taken a look at the documentation and it says: "The default value is the minimum size, 8 MB; there is no maximum size." I think this means that there IS a default size equal to the minimum (8MB), isn't it?
Anyway, thank you for you answer!

Comment: @DavidAlfonso The GFlags documentation for /tracedb clearly states "Sets the maximum size of the user-mode stack trace database for the process."  The part of the documentation you're quoting "there is no maximum size" means the maximum size is unlimited.

SizeInMB is a whole number representing the number of megabytes in decimal units. The default value is the minimum size, 8 MB; there is no maximum size. To revert to the default size, set SizeInMB to 0.

Comment: @buzz3791 This question is almost 10 years old, but thank you anyway, maybe others can benefit from your comment!

Comment: looks like the most up to date behavior of /tracedb is that by default it's max 32MB for 32bit and 64MB for 64bit windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-umdh-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak